# How to join two tables with ActiveRecord methods in CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

I have some data submitted into db_table(e.g lodge), some of which are id_no from another table(e.g room_type). When I try to fetch data from the db_table(lodge) to my view which comes in array, it returns the id value(room_type_id) submitted which is fine.
But the goal is to print the room_type_name from the room_type table. How do I do this?

**My Controller**

```
public function invoice($lodge_no = '') {
    $data = [
        'page_name' => 'Invoice',
        'page_title' => 'Invoice | The Ashokas',
        'invoice_data' => $this->lodgeModel->fetchInvoiceData($lodge_no)
    ];
    return view('lodge/invoice', $data);
}
```

**My Model**

```
public function fetchInvoiceData($lodge_no) {
    $builder = $this->db->table('lodge');
    $builder->where('lodge_no', $lodge_no);
    $result = $builder->get();
    if (count ($result->getResultArray()) > 0) {
        return $result->getRowArray();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**My View**

```
<td class="text-center">
    <div><strong>Room No:</strong></div>
    <div class="text-muted"><?= $invoice_data['room_type_id'] ?> - Room <?= $invoice_data['room_id'] ?></div>
</td>
```

My Views print **Room No: 5 - Room 5**
The first 5 is the room_type_id but I want it to display the room_title(Hibiscus) assigned with this id 5 in the room_type database as shown in the database image below
[image]

**Lodge Database**
[image]

Comment: As an aside, you might like to read about `getWhere()`. I also recommend that you unconditionally `return $result->getResultArray();`.  This way your view can unconditionally feed the data into a `foreach()`.  If you need some special behavior in your view when the array is empty, then you only need to check `if (!$invoice_data)` because an empty array is considered `falsey`.

Comment: I would probably reduce the model method's body to one line: `public function fetchInvoiceData(int $lodge_no): array { return $this->db->table('lodge')->getWhere(['lodge_no', $lodge_no)->getRowArray(); }`.  That said, I think you want to write a JOIN query, but I don't understand your table structures/relationships from the provided details.  Before trying to translate the query to active record, try to code it in raw SQL and run in your PHPMyAdmin to test.

Comment: please add table `lodge` structure. also: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I have added the lodge table